# adding variable to python function using other variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like pass the variables into the function that uses range(). How do I pass variable C that has more then one number via one variable. Something like range(5, 10, 2)?

Here is my example code:

```
a = 0
b = 10
c = 2   
def num_count(a, b, c):
        for number in range(c):
            a += b
        print("New Count is: {0}".format(a))
```

I tried passing it as a string and converting it to an integer as well as by using a list. Nothing worked.

Comment: You mean like `c=(5,10,2)` then `range(*c)` ?

Comment: Yes. I keep getting errors that I am passing a string.

Comment: Then stop passing a string.

Comment: Create the `range` outside the function and pass it in…? What's the best approach is very debatable with such artificial scenarios.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks. Can you tell me what * is in there for?

Comment: It means "expand this variable" so it becomes three arguments to `range`. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: @deceze Thanks. At this moment I am trying to learn the syntax and get a feel for the language. So I am kind of making up things on my own so that I could learn how everything works. Thanks to you I will now know that I will have to check on that later in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass in the range like you mentioned with only a small change to the 
for loop

```
a = 0
b = 10
c = range(5, 10, 2)   
def num_count(a, b, c):
    for number in c:
        a += b
    print("New Count is: {0}".format(a))

num_count(a,b,c)
```

or, as khelwood* mentioned, pass in a list/tuple and expand it with `*`

```
a = 0
b = 10
c = (5, 10, 2)   
def num_count(a, b, c):
    for number in range(*c):
        a += b
    print("New Count is: {0}".format(a))

num_count(a,b,c)
```

both output 30 which is expected